# Number of records inferior to the number of rows - vertical scrollbar

Tags: jqgrid

If `reccount < rownum` then I have an "empty column" after the last column. How to avoid this phenomena?  In fact this column has the dimension of the vertical scrollbar!

Comment: Could you include more full code which you use. The best would be the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Right, space is often reserved for a vertical scrollbar even if there are not enough rows in the grid to require a scrollbar. See [jqgrid-is-there-a-way-to-always-display-a-vertical-scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575051/jqgrid-is-there-a-way-to-always-display-a-vertical-scrollbar) for some ideas on how to always display the vertical scrollbar, to ensure the space is filled.

Alternatively, if you know there will never be enough rows to require the scrollbar, you can set the `scrollOffset` to `0` to reclaim the space. From the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> **scrollOffset**
>
> integer
>
> Determines the width of the vertical scrollbar. Since different browsers interpret this width differently (and it is difficult to calculate it in all browsers) this can be changed.

Comment: +1 from me. Now I understand what Bertaud means under "empty column". By the way if one use `height: "auto"` or `height: "100%"` the width of the grid will be correct calculated and no "empty column" will be seen after the last column.

Comment: No ! in that case a horizontal scrollbar is displayed when the reccount is greater than recnum ! if reccount <= recnum then no vertical scrollbar and no empty space else vertical scrollbar