# Sorting enable for a limited number of columns

Tags: jqgrid

In a grid with 5 columns, I would like to have the possibility of sorting only for columns 2 and 4.
What is the correct demarch for implement this ?
- declare sortable to true for columns 2 and 4
- what else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value of `sortable` property is already `true` (see here). So you have to include

```js
sortable: false
```

property in the definition of all columns in `colModel` with exception columns 2 and 4. If you have many columns, then it would be better to change defaults for `colModel` items:

```js
cmTemplate: { sortable: false }
```

After that you should include `sortable: true` in columns 2 and 4. In the way you can change any other defaults for `colModel`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details.

Comment: @Bertaud: You are welcome! What answer about "empty column" you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178575/number-of-records-inferior-to-the-number-of-rows-vertical-scrollbar